# Android javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext in Kotlin and minifyEnabled

Tags: java, android, kotlin, minify

In an Android app, I implement the interface javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext in several places.  The interface has 3 methods, I only care about 1 (we throw an exception if either of other two are called).  The signature for the one we care about is:

```
    String getNamespaceURI(String prefix);
```

The implementations were in Java, now they in Kotlin.    The Kotlin implementations seemed to be working fine until last night when I started to test with "minifyEnabled true".

With minifyEnabled, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class ‘mypackage.content.loader.EPubNamespaceResolver' does not implement interface 'javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext' in call to 'java.l
                        ang.String javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext.getNamespaceURI(java.lang.String)' (declaration of 'org.apache.xpath.jaxp.JAXPPrefixResolver' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/apache-xml.jar)
                     E      at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.JAXPPrefixResolver.getNamespaceForPrefix(JAXPPrefixResolver.java:47)
                     E      at org.apache.xpath.compiler.Lexer.mapNSTokens(Lexer.java:596)
                     E      at org.apache.xpath.compiler.Lexer.tokenize(Lexer.java:365)
                     E      at org.apache.xpath.compiler.Lexer.tokenize(Lexer.java:98)
                     E      at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.initXPath(XPathParser.java:112)
                     E      at org.apache.xpath.XPath.<init>(XPath.java:178)
                     E      at org.apache.xpath.XPath.<init>(XPath.java:266)
                     E      at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(XPathImpl.java:195)
                     E      at org.apache.xpath.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(XPathImpl.java:281)
```

I didn't have any proguard rules for it in Java, it just worked.  I tried putting proguard rules to keep it, I tried @Keep. I tried playing with whether the param and return type were nullable or not.   I just can't make it work with  minifyEnabled in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding proguard rules as `-keep class javax.xml.** { *; }`. Once you get it executed successfully. Then, reduce the scope for more optimisation. With the error log it looks like your interface is getting minified as well.

Comment: I've tried:-keep class javax.xml.** { *; }

-keep class javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext { *; }
-keep public class * implements javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext
 and a keep on my class.   None of that is working.

Comment: And none of explains that fact that it works without any of that when the interface is implemented in Java.

Comment: If you can share any sample. I would love to try and help you :)

Answer (score 0):

in the end, I implement the interface in place:

```
    private val namespaceResolver = object : NamespaceContext {
        override fun getNamespaceURI(prefix: String?): String {
            requireNotNull(prefix) { "No prefix provided!" }
            return when (prefix) {
...
                else -> {
                    throw IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected prefix")
                }
            }
        }

        override fun getPrefix(namespaceURI: String?): String {
            error("Not implemented")
        }

        override fun getPrefixes(namespaceURI: String?): MutableIterator<Any?> {
            error("Not implemented")
        }
    }
```

With it implemented in place, the problem went away.